# export 'watch' (imported as 'watch') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, tinymce

I do have an error after installing the tinymce vue js in my project

Here is my Editor.vue

```
<editor
    :init="{
     height: 500,
     menubar: false,
     plugins: [
       'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
       'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
       'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
     ],
     toolbar:
       'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
       alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
       bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
       }" />
```

Then I import
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';
import '@tinymce/tinymce-vue/lib/browser/tinymce-vue.min.js';

```
export default {
    components: {
        'editor':Editor
    }
}
```

This is my error
[image]

Comment: Hi, I think you don't need the second import.

Comment: Hi @YashMaheshwari, I tried to remove the second import, but the error still persist